# Express POST response-object not being updated when request parameter is changed

Tags: json, ajax, node.js, express, global-variables

I am trying to make a tool to view our projects configuration JSON file. The config is generated based on what process.env variables are set. I've created an express server with one route that listens for the environment variables and returns the corresponding JSON configuration. However this only works on the first request, the correct process.env variables are being changed, but the JSON config being returned only reflects the first request made. Below is the POST route - the fpconf object should change to reflect the request parameters being sent. Is there some something I'm missing?

```
app.post( '/json', function ( req, res, next ) {
res.header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" );
res.header( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested- With, Content-Type, Accept" );

console.log( req.body );
_.merge( process.env, req.body );// Sets environment variables grabbed from post request
console.log( process.env ); // Log to ensure environment variables have been changed.

var fpUtils = appRootPath.require( '/libs/helpers/fputils' ),
fpconf = appRootPath.require( '/libs/fp-conf' );///file that returns the configuration JSON
console.log( "instance is " + process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE + ", deployment is " + process.env.NODE_ENV )

console.log(fpconf.data);
res.send( fpconf.data );

});
```

Comment: Updated data gets sent back if i'm running the file with nodemon. I think I solved it! I guess the server has to restart when an environment variable is changed?